# Kill client established connection in router

Tags: security, iptables, router, tcp

I am doing a security research related to the damage you can do if you control the router. I need to be able to close/reset a established connection from one client while sitting on the router.

To be more specific, I need to kill the connection between a client and the Apple Push notification server (APNS). The reason is that I want to be able to prevent the client from communicating with APNS. I tried using iptables but it won't work on established connections.

Given that there is a established connection to APNS from the moment the client turns on his Macbook, by the time I compromise the router it's to late.

I tried iptables, to change the arp table, used the "route" and "ip route" commands. Nothing worked...

How can I kill a established connection when I control the router so I can add rules to iptables that prevent a new connection?

I will add that I do not want to install new tools like tcpkill or cutter. I would like to find a way to do this with the tools that come in the OS out of the box on distros like dd-wrt and openwrt.

Answer (score 1):

Approach:

1. Block `NEW` connections from your target with `iptables`. You are already doing this.
2. Delete all conntrack state for the existing connections from your victim

For step 2, you want to use: 
`conntrack - command line interface for netfilter connection tracking` (`man conntrack`)

In debian/ubuntu, you can install the package `conntrack`.

And now, just delete the state for your victim.

```
conntrack -D -s src -d dst
conntrack -D -s dst -d src
```

Since your victim can't establish new connections (yes, iptables conntrack will now consider the packets from the existing connection as `NEW`), you achieved your goal.

By the way, `conntrack -F` is your friend when experimenting with state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @corny. One of my restrictions is installing tools. I do not want to install anything in the router I am compromising and ideally want to find a way to do it with the common tools that come in small linux distros like dd-wrt or openwrt. Apart from the conntrack, I saw other tools like tcpkill and cutter which could achieve the same thing but I will prefer not to install anything and work with what the OS provides out of the box. Thanks again!

Comment: I just `strace`d the `conntrack` tool, it is remarkably simple: it just tells the kernel what to do over an `PF_NETLINK` `NETLINK_NETFILTER` socket. You can probably implement this yourself in python (which is available on your router?) or compile the conntrack-tool as static binary for your router.